# Error with uploading my google chrome extnsion

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey guys i have planned to upload my google chrome.

According to the documentation i have made the whole file in a zip format with the `manifest.json` in the root  directory.

But when i select the file and uploaded it to the web store it shows me error like

`An error occurred: Failed to process your item.
Invalid package. Please make sure it is a valid zip file and the file manifest.json is at the root directory of the zip package.`

Can anyone tell me why am getting like this ??..

Any help would be appreciated ..Thanx in advance

Comment: Are you sure that your zip _starts_ at the folder with `manifest.json` and does not _contain_ a folder with it instead as a folder?

Comment: @Xan my zip contains the files including the icons and the manifest.json ..it doesnt contain any folders inside the zip.

Comment: What did you use to make the zip file?

Comment: It could also be a transmission error. Retry sending the file.

Comment: @Xan i have used winrar..but still the problem persists

Comment: @Xan could you please help me ??..am really stuck

Comment: If you don't mind, upload the file somewhere so we can take a look. But I won't be immediately available to comment on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem was with the winrar actually.I have removed the application and just compressed with deafault.
Now it uploads fine

Comment: You probably selected the wrong compression method. I never had problems with WinRAR-produced archives.

Comment: @Xan can you please answer this if you know http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691102/finding-the-estimated-time-with-google-chrome

Comment: yeah, damn winrar, windows default zip feature works! select all files in extension dir --> right click -> send to -> zip file

Answer (score 13):

I was having this issue today. My issue seems to stem from the new MacOS update. First I tried to compress using Mac's built in zipper, which kept giving me the error on Chrome Webstore that I was missing the manifest.json file.

I then zipped it online, which I was able to easily upload to the Chrome Web Store.

Comment: I have the same with the MacOS default compressor.

Answer (score 12):

I have the same problem, it's because of the Mac default compressor. You can use below commands to zip the built folder,

```bash
cd dist/ # where the extension stored
zip -r dist.zip *
```

Comment: This is work for me. Thanks.